# Change the order by field based on a condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a scenario where I have to change the order by field based on some condition.

```
from summaryRows in _summaryTable.AsEnumerable()
where summaryRows.Field<string>("AirlineDisplayName")
                 .Equals(airlineName_, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
orderby summaryRows.Field<decimal>("FareAdult")
select new
{
    summaryTableRow = summaryRows
};
```

Based on the condition, I have to change the order by field to `orderby summaryRows.Field<double>("BasePricePlusTaxAndFees")`
Here, both the field data type is different.  How can I do it in one query?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the most readable using fluent Linq syntax and introducing an if-statement while building the query.. Since you do not explain your condition, I assume that you have a boolean variable called condition with the appropriate value:

```
var query = _summaryTable.AsEnumerable()
     .Where(
         summaryRows => summaryRows.Field<string>("AirlineDisplayName")
             .Equals(airlineName_, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

if (condition)
    query = query.OrderBy(summaryRows => summaryRows.Field<decimal>("FareAdult"));
else
    query = query.OrderBy(summaryRows => summaryRows.Field<double>("BasePricePlusTaxAndFees"));

var resultQuery = query.Select(summaryRows => new
    {
        summaryTableRow = summaryRows
    });
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested it, but good luck.

Comment: One problem though, you'll probably need to declare a separate variable for the projection at the end.  `query` has is an enumerable of `DataRow` up to the sorting.  The projection changes the type to an enumerable of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
orderby conditionIsTrue ? (IComparable)summaryRows.Field<double>("BasePricePlusTaxAndFees") : (IComparable)summaryRows.Field<decimal>("FareAdult")
```